# Why is my component rendering a count twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**my parent layout component:**

```
function MainPage() {
    return(
        <div>
            <MLayout children={<MNavbar custOrFalse={false} />} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default MainPage;
```

**my child navbar component:**

```
 const Navbar = ({...props},{children}) => {

    const [grid, makeGrid] = useState(false); //whatever is inside the parenthesis is the starting value
    const [publish, makePublish] = useState(false);
    const [research, makeResearch] = useState(false);
    const [custOrFalse, makeCustToggle] = useState(props.custOrFalse);
    const [custCount,setCount] = useState(0);
   

    function CustToggle(){
      makeCustToggle(prevVal=>!prevVal); //useState is an async function, so need to use the previous value.
    }

    //can set this navbar to be cust based or not
    var custButton='cust page'
    if ( custOrFalse===true ) {
      custButton='cust login' 
    };
    var countFirst = (custCount == 0);
    console.log(countFirst)

    // useEffect(()=>{
    //   console.log(custCount);
    // },[custOrFalse]);
    console.log(custCount);

    return (
      <div>
          <nav className = {`${styles.page__menu} ${styles.page__custom_settings} ${styles.menu}`} >
            <ul className = {`${styles.menu__list} ${styles.r_list}`} >
                <CustomNavButtonLeft navbutton='the grid'         />
                <CustomNavButtonLeft navbutton='publish'          />
                <CustomNavButtonLeft navbutton='research'         />
                <CustomNavButtonRight navbutton={custButton} onClick={CustToggle,()=> setCount(custCount + 1)}  />
            </ul>
          </nav>
          {custOrFalse&&<Registration/>}
          {countFirst&&!custOrFalse&&<DLogin/>}
      </div>
      );
  };


export default Navbar;
```

i'm trying to get the button on the navbar to toggle between texts as well as toggle between components it renders - BUT have the first rendering not show a component that i havent created yet, so in effect, show nothing.

when i run this code, the console log displays:

```
true
0
false
```

i was under the impression it would simply display `true`, but for some reason the count is made as soon as the component is rendered it seems?

from research what i understand, useEffect is an async function - but i'm not sure how that impacts the flow here

**updated** to show that once the counter is added, the toggle stops working

Comment: minor suggestion : your variable has the name `custCount` and your function also has the name `custCount()` this might get confusing, this should have been caught by a linter, but  it's just a readability thing

Comment: `useEffect` being async means that the `console.log(custCount)` will actually be updated in the next render instead of the present render, if you move the `console.log` out of the `useEffect` you will see the difference in your console.

Comment: a closure might have be tricky even in simple examples. setCount(custCount + 1);  => setCount(pre =>prev + 1);  Even if this is not solution, pls read this https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Comment: something that i don't understand here : you could have just done `onClick={()=> setCount(count + 1)}` directly, why are you going through all this trouble?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar because it didnt work lol

Comment: use `console.log` outside of `useEffect`, that would help you a lot better during debugging, you could try what i wrote in the comment, this round-about way could get annoying very fast.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar it is definitely annoying.  ```makeCustToggle(prevVal=>!prevVal);``` it seems that when i added the counter, it stopped toggling - is there a way to do something like prevVal.custOrFalse so that it only focuses on the value of a variable?

Comment: I didn't understand, can you update the question with your latest problem?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar updated

Comment: if you're trying to call both the methods `onClick` you should do `onClick={()=>  { CustToggle(); setCount(custCount + 1)}}` instead of your current syntax

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar that did it!!!!! wow, very good to know thank you

Comment: i'll post it as an answer, you can then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're trying to call both the methods onClick you should do

````
onClick={()=>  { 
   CustToggle();
   setCount(custCount + 1)
}}

``` instead of your current syntax
````

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using old value of `custCount` your state setter should accept a callback argument ([state updates may be asynchronous in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)).

```
()=> setCount(count=> count+1).
```

Also, you are initializing a state from props. This is an **antipattern** in React.

```
const [custOrFalse, makecustToggle] = useState(props.custOrFalse);
```

See [this medium article](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e):

Personally, I'd rewrite your `Navbar` component as follows, to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` :

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {grid:false, publish: false, research: false, custOrFalse: false, custCount: 0};
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        return {custOrFalse: props.custOrFalse};
    }


    custToggle = ()=>{
        this.setState(oldState=> {
            return {custToggle: !oldState.custToggle, custCount: oldState.custCount+1};
        });
    }
    

    render() {
        // .....
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time, i really appreciate it.  i'm a bit confused as to the solution of the antipattern if lets say i want to start a navbar with a different state in case the user is logged in...

Comment: `getDerivedState` runs before the 1st render. In this method, you can return *state properties* whose **initial values** depend on `props`. You can use it with a `loggedIn` prop if needed.